# Embedded resources in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, embedded-resource

I have a library in both C# and Java that use some XML files to generate a lot of objects. I use them so I don't have to hardcode it in both languages, and can easily update the data.

In both C# and Java I can embed these files into the DLL/Package.

How would I proceed to do something like this in Objective-C?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a language level question, it's a platform packaging level question. On both Mac OS X and iOS, typically you'll add the resource file to your project, then get the path to the file from `NSBundle`:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"xml"];
```

Libraries in Objective-C are called frameworks. Like applications, they are also bundles on Mac OS X and instead of `mainBundle` you probably want to use `bundleForClass:`.

iOS does not support frameworks, only static libraries, so you won't be able to include your resource files with your library on that platform. They must be added directly to the project.

Comment: So if I understand correctly for a iOS app, I need to add the library and seperately add the XML files to the iOS project?

Comment: I decided to embed the xml data as a large static string in my objective-c classes, so they are portable for me.

Comment: You've contradicted yourself. "Libraries in Objective-C are called frameworks." Later you say "iOS does not support frameworks, only static libraries." How can iOS support a library, which in Objective-C is called a framework, if iOS does not itself support frameworks? Libraries are different from Frameworks.

Comment: You're being pedantic, but I'll go along with it. Frameworks are a superset of libraries. They bundle code, public headers and other resources in a single package. iOS does not support creating your own frameworks or dynamically loadable libraries. The only option is static (link-time) libraries. The original question was about how to bundle both code and non-code files into a single package for Objective-C. Frameworks are the answer, but due to a limitation on iOS, they cannot be used and non-code resources must be added directly to the project.